How to use pyspark column values to index a numpy array?
I have a pyspark dataframe with two columns representing the 2d index of an array. I want to add the specific values of that array as a new column to my df.
array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (0, 2),
        (1, 1),
        (1, 2)
    ],
    ["x", "y"]  
)


I tried to pass the columns to the array (which obviously didn't work). I get the error:
IndexError: only integers, slices(':'), ellipsis('...'), numpy.newaxis ('None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.
This makes sense as i actually tried passing a column.
df.withColumn("value", array[col("x")][col("y")])

Ideally, my result uses the indexes from the df to navigate the array and pull the values.
value = [3,5,6]

I would appreciate any help with this. I am specifically trying to utilize pyspark functionality to do this.

Your array object is a list, not a numpy array!  Show the actual error for each thing you try.

I updated it to reflect the array

I'd suggest getting the indexing to work with arrays before you try to convert your columns to arrays.

How big is the array and df?

The df has ~2800000 rows. That's of the actual index coordinates (x, y). The array has a shape of ~7800, 7600..

if this was a pandas dataframe, i could define a function that returns the value array[x][y], then use df.apply to apply it to the columns, but I am relatively new to spark and I am trying too find out how to work with its functionality to do this

With a pandas dataframe, df.x.to_numpy() would return a integer array tbat can be used for indexing.  Make sure you understand the difference between indexing a 2d array with arr[x,y] and arr[x][y].

Based on the size of your dataframe, you might want to compute successive operations in Spark or Possibly Pandas if you loaded in Pandas. I don't know what you want to do after value = [3,5,6] but converting that size of Pyspark dataframe's data into Pandas or pure Python's list is expensive.

I ended up utilizing a vectorized UDF approach.
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType


vector =  VectorAssembler(inputCols =["x", "y"], 
                          outputCol= "v").transform(df)
def loc_img_value(x):
    return int(array[int(x[0])][int(x[1])])

get_img_value = F.udf(lambda x: loc_img_value(x), IntegerType())

vector = vector.withColumn("Value", get_img_value("v"))



If you want the value in a PySpark column, you can do this as a non-UDF approach.
# Convert numpy array to Spark column.
array_col = F.array([F.array([F.lit(x.item()) for x in y]) for y in array])

df = df.withColumn("value", array_col.getItem(F.col('x')).getItem(F.col('y')))

